# C# Variable scope in switch statement

Tags: c#, scope

I have a function that begins with this:

```
    void RecordLoadPosition()
    {
        OdbcCommand command;
        if (_hasPlantGenie)
        {
            command = new OdbcCommand();
            string query;
            switch (ItemType)
            {
                case ItemTypeEnum.COIL:
                    // We're only going to add records to the coils_pg table when the coil gets moved.  After
                    // a record is added, we'll update it.
                   command = new OdbcCommand("select * from coils_pg where coil_id = " + _itemName, _db);
```

When I compile this, I do not get an error on the first line in the if block, but I get errors complaining that I cannot use "command" before it is declared inside the case block.  I don't understand why the declaration at the top of the function is not available inside the case block.

But OK.  If it's not visible in the case block, I can just declare it.  I changed the first statement in the case block to "OdbcCommand command...".  Now I get an error complaining that I can't declare a variable that is already declared in a parent block!  I can't win either way!

What is happening here?

Of course, I can just use different OdbcCommand objects, and that's what I'll do for now, but I'd like to understand this.

=============================================

It does appear that something is missing in my original code sample, but I have no idea what.  Here is a small function that should have shown the same error, but did not:

```
    void ScopeTest()
    {
        OdbcCommand command = null;
        if (_hasPlantGenie)
        {
            command = new OdbcCommand();
            switch (ItemType)
            {
                case ItemTypeEnum.COIL:
                    // We're only going to add records to the coils_pg table when the coil gets moved.  After
                    // a record is added, we'll update it.
                    command = new OdbcCommand();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

==============================================

And, because people asked for it, here is the complete original function (including the extra creation of an OdbcCommand object at the top of the if block merely to demonstrate that it does not throw an error:

```
    void RecordLoadPosition()
    {
        OdbcCommand command = null;
        if (_hasPlantGenie)
        {
            command = new OdbcCommand();
            string query;
            switch (ItemType)
            {
                case ItemTypeEnum.COIL:
                    // We're only going to add records to the coils_pg table when the coil gets moved.  After
                    // a record is added, we'll update it.
                    command = new OdbcCommand("select * from coils_pg where coil_id = " + _itemName, _db);
                    OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        query = "update plant_genie.coils_pg set x_coordinate = " +
                                XPosCurrent.ToString() +
                                ", y_coordinate = " +
                                YPosCurrent.ToString() +
                                " where coil_id = '" +
                                _itemName + "'";
                        reader.Close();
                        command.CommandText = query;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        query = "insert into plant_genie.coils_pg(coil_id, x_coordinate, y_coordinate) values (" +
                                XPosCurrent.ToString() + YPosCurrent.ToString() +
                                "'" + _itemName + "')";
                        reader.Close();
                        command.CommandText = query;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    break;
                case ItemTypeEnum.INNER_COVER:
                    // The inner_cover_pg table will be pre-built.  We can assume that it has records for
                    // each inner cover.
                    query = "select set_inner_cover_down(" +
                            XPosCurrent.ToString() +
                            ", " +
                            YPosCurrent.ToString() + 
                            ", '" +
                            _itemName +
                            "')";
                    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, _db);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    // See if the cover has been set down in a storage location.  If it has
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you instantiating the object to a new OdbcCommand() when you will be doing it below in the switch?

Comment: Your error description doesn't make sense. You wouldn't get a use before declare error when assigning a variable. Can you paste in some more of your code?

Comment: I get no such errors in a comparable example of my own.  Please provide a **complete** example of the code that demonstrates the problem.  That said, my guess is you're accessing `command` after the end of the `if` statement, or in a `catch` block, at which point it may not have been assigned a value, and *that's* where you're getting an error.

Comment: I instantiate the object at the top of the if statement merely to demonstrate that I can do so without having the compiler flag it as an error.  I can use the variable named command outside of the switch without throwing an error, but when I use it the same way inside the switch, I get an error.

Comment: @Servy Does C# cause compilation errors when accessing an unassigned variable?

Comment: @Asad If it's a local variable, and if you're reading from it, yes.  If it's a field, or if you're only writing to it, then no.

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON Again, please post the **complete** body of this method, exactly as it is in the code where you are observing the error. Also post the exact compilation error you are seeing.

Comment: Can you post the complete code? I think the main issue is missing here.

Comment: Counterexample (which I expected to show the error but did not) has been added to my original post.

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON You're not listening to what we're saying. The counterexample doesn't help us identify your problem. Please post the original `RecordLoadPosition` method in its entirety, as well as the exact text of the compiler error.

Comment: I am listening.  I had hoped that the tiny example would show the error.  I posted it anyway since it added information that might be useful, either to you or to me, to understand the problem.  I have now posted the complete original function.

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON So in your last code snippet what is the exact error, and on what line is it?  Also, we really don't need to see all of the code, we just need you to create the smallest example that you can that **still replicates your problem**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `case ItemTypeEnum.INNER_COVER:` condition, you have:

```
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, _db);
```

You're redeclaring it, when you should just be assigning it like you are in the `case ItemTypeEnum.COIL:` branch. Replace that line with this:

```
command = new OdbcCommand(query, _db);
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks very much to you and to all who took the time to help me with this!  It didn't occur to me that the root source of the problem could be below the line on which the error was reported.  I don't think I've ever seen that before.